# Как поймать событие iframe location change?

Tags: html, dom, iframe, cross-domain

Есть сайт, в нём есть `iframe`, в который подгружается другой сайт.
Хочется подсветить `BODY` зелёным, когда в `iframe` полностью загрузился другой сайт, и вывести `alert` когда `location` `iframe`'a сменится с дэфолтного(заранее определённого) на какой-либо другой.

Как это сделать?

Comment: onload не поймаешь https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes#кросс-доменность-ограничение-доступа-к-окну

Answer (score 0):

Элемент iframe является обычным узлом DOM, как и любой другой. Существенное отличие – в том, что с ним связан объект window внутреннего окна. Он доступен по ссылке iframe.contentWindow.

Таким образом, iframe.contentWindow.document будет внутренним документом, iframe.contentWindow.document.body – его  и так далее.

https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes

Comment: "Например, чтобы узнать об окончании загрузки <iframe>, мы можем повесить обработчик iframe.onload. По сути, это то же самое что iframe.contentWindow.onload, но его мы можем поставить лишь в случае, если окно с того же источника." https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes#кросс-доменность-ограничение-доступа-к-окну